# How to change the date format in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

I have a variable which stores the date as "18/07/2013". I need to parse this to "07/18/2013". How this is possible in jquery?

```
var date = $("#dte").val();
```

Comment: It's impossible in jQuery. jQuery does not have any date formatting tools.

Comment: This is what regular JavaScript is capable of!

Comment: If you need to do anything more complicated with those dates, consider using Moment.js.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = $("#dte").val();

d=date.split('/');

newdate=d[2]+"/"+d[1]+"/"+d[0];

return newdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var date = $("#dte").val().replace(/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)/, "$2/$1");
```

to swap month and date part.

Answer (score 1):

A simple replace would do the trick:

```
date = date.replace(/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\//, "$2/$1/");
```

No need of jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = $("#dte").val().split('/');
var newDate = date[1]+'/'+date[0]+'/'+date[2];
alert(newDate); // or $("#dte").val(newDate); if you want to update the input
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. 
It helped me to format date in jQuery

```
 $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(yourDateString))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [jQuery dateFormat](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) jquery plugin..you can use that for show date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var date = date.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)/, "$2/$1/$3");
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3upKW/)**

Answer (score 0):

javascript's Date accepts a string in the format `year / month / day`, so just reverse the order and create a date object :

```
var date = '18/07/2013';
var dObj = new Date(date.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

var newD = dObj.getDate() + '/' + (dObj.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dObj.getFullYear();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6F35t/)